# Is it possible to repair iso images incorrectly made with dd in OSX Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, dvd, iso-image, dd, compact-disc

About a year ago, I made rips of a bunch of my CD/DVD games and packed the originals away.

The problem is that now I'm trying to use WinXP Pro on VirtualBox on OSX Snow Leopard to play these iso images. I used dd in Terminal to make most or all of these images, but when I try to load them as a virtual cd in VirtualBox, they don't work.

I tried iso files I obtained by other means, and they worked fine, so I tried diskutil to find out more. The error message I get from trying to mount throught that is, "No mountable file systems." The only disk image that works was from a dvd.

I've forgotten the exact paths or options (probably none) I used when I made these images, but I know I used dd.

Reading around, I found the following link:

[dd producing corrupt ISO images on Snow Leopard (whether invoked from a script or the shell)](https://superuser.com/questions/105942/dd-producing-corrupt-iso-images-on-snow-leopard-whether-invoked-from-a-script-o)

From this, I'm guessing there's a high likelihood that I did the dd wrong (e.g. dd if=/dev/disk1 of=image.iso). If so, is there any way to manually repair these images, or will I have to download or re-dd these?

(Also, for my own learning, is this an OSX-specific dd bug/feature, or linux, too? Was I ignorant in thinking that dd if=/dev/whatever of=whatever.img would give a raw binary dump?)

Comment: "Was I ignorant in thinking that dd if=/dev/whatever of=whatever.img would give a raw binary dump?" - not really. However, in your above example I can see **dd if=/dev/disk1** - meaning, that it would actually be copying a partition (an offset from the start of the disk). Was that really the case or were you copying the whole disk to start with?